# rich:suggestionbox work after 4. character I entered

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I hava a java project that works with jsf and has many rich:suggestionbox. They are working good but I need them work after I enter 4. character to inputbox. The list that retrieved is too long and waiting too much. Do you have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `minChars="4"` to your suggestion box.